# iPhone asks for iCloud password on power charge

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

Whenever I plug my iPhone to charge it, iCloud asks me to re-enter my password. How can I fix this?

I'm using iOS 11.4.

Comment: I am having the same problem. It seems to be causing my apple watch to dump all my synced songs as well.

Comment: Also happening on iOS 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the settings has solved the problem.